# imagecrop adiciona linha preta

Tags: php

Estou fazendo um script que lê um xml e depois recorta as coordenadas dele na imagem e em seguida a salva, porém a função "imagecrop" sempre adiciona uma linha preta no final das imagens e eu simplesmente não posso mudar o tamanho e nem apagar a linha preta já que quase todas chegam até a borda. Estou usando 2 códigos, um gera a imagem e outro baixa.

crop2.php

```
$ini_filename = 'assets/sprites/achievements.png';
$im = imagecreatefrompng($ini_filename);

$xml = simplexml_load_file('assets/sprites/achievements.xml');
foreach ($xml->SubTexture as $sub) {
    $to_crop_array = array('x' => $sub['x'] , 'y' => $sub['y'], 'width' => $sub['width'], 'height' => $sub['height']);
    $thumb_im = imagecrop($im, $to_crop_array);

    if ($_GET['name'] == $sub['name']) {
        imagepng($thumb_im);
    }
}
```

e crop.php

```
<?php
ini_set('allow_url_fopen', TRUE);

$xml = simplexml_load_file('assets/sprites/achievements.xml');
foreach ($xml->SubTexture as $sub) {

    file_put_contents('images/' . $sub['name'] . '.png', file_get_contents('http://localhost/apk/crop2?name=' . $sub['name']));
}
```

e eu queria saber como remover essa linha sem danificar nada.

Comment: Existe um [Bug #67447 reportado](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67447) recentemente sobre este assunto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu levei a essência do seu problema, ou seja, o bug da imagecrop(), para o SOEN e pedi uma versão alternativa que, além de não sofrer do mesmo bug ainda funciona em versões anteriores a 5.5 do PHP. Eis a função:

```
function mycrop($src, array $rect)
{
    $dest = imagecreatetruecolor($rect['width'], $rect['height']);
    imagecopyresized(
        $dest,
        $src,
        0,
        0,
        $rect['x'],
        $rect['y'],
        $rect['width'],
        $rect['height'],
        $rect['width'],
        $rect['height']
    );

    return $dest;
}
```

Para testar usei o mesmo script do bug que o Zuul comentou, só mudei a cor de branco para amarelo e enviei um header() para a imagem aparecer diretamente no browser:

```
$image = imagecreatetruecolor(500, 500);
imagefill($image, 0, 0, imagecolorallocate($image, 255, 255, 0));

$ressource = mycrop($image, ['x' => 0, 'y' => 0, 'width' => 250, 'height' => 250]);

header( 'Content-type: image/jpeg' );

imagejpeg($ressource);
```

E ao executar você vê um quadrado amarelo de 250px de largura e altura sem a borda preta adicional.

Espero que ajude, assim posso recompensar quem me deu a solução.

Comment: Se possível, gostaria de uma confirmação quanto a solução pois esta veio do SOEN e, quem a desenvolveu, poderia receber o devido agradecimento.